# Is it possible to use both swift coding and UI interface storyboards on the same project to build an app on xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, swift3

I find it really hard to implement certain things using storyboards and it requires some code. So can you use storyboards for whatever is possible to implement it with and rest of the things with code? Does xcode work like that? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These sentences are true:

It is possible to develop by **coding** in Swift/Objective C **and building interface** in Storyboard.

It is also **possible** **to develop an app without storyboard**.

It is **not possible** to use **storyboards without code**.

Here is a good article:

https://www.toptal.com/ios/ios-user-interfaces-storyboards-vs-nibs-vs-custom-code

> Storyboards are best used with multiple interconnected view controllers, as their major simplification is in transitioning between view controllers.

Comment: Thank you for these sentences. I also find them true now (:

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use both code and storyboards to build a UI. I would say it’s the way most non-trivial apps are written.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.